# Mailchimp and old users

Tags: mailchimp

I have a database of users who signed up for my web application over the past few months.

Now I would like to use Mailchimp to send them newsletters. Can I just add their email addresses to a distribution list and start sending them newsletters or, before that, will Mailchimp send them an email asking them whether they want to be added to my distribution list?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, MailChimp supports both single and double optin lists, and will only send out a double optin confirmation email when a user signs up through a mailchimp form (or API).  If you import a list then it's assumed the users have already opted in and no welcome email is sent.

They do watch unsubscribe / complaint rates very closely though so is important to make sure your list is clean otherwise your account can get closed.  If you are setting up a new account just for this guess it isn't too much of a worry but could be if it is an existing account.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this once before with less than satisfactory results.

I had a database of around 2,000 users and added them all to a Mailchimp list.  Mailchimp provides the ability for users to report spam, and their tolerance is incredibly strict.  I think I had maybe 4-5 accounts report my message as spam (out of 2,000+), and Mailchimp immediately suspended my account.

I was able to get it re-activated after promising to implement an opt-in mechanism.  The problem was, I used to actually *have* an opt-in mechanism where you had to check a box saying you wanted to be added to a mailing list, however out of several hundred users, I never once had anyone check that box.  When I made it checked by default, I never had anyone uncheck it.  So I just figured no one cared.

Mailchimp does have an API, so it's possible to integrate your user database with Mailchimp and provide a UI mechanism for people to subscribe and unsubscribe to newsletters.

Comment: maybe you were using their free plan, that's why it wasn't easy to get your account re-activated.

Comment: Yea, I haven't sent out bulk email since.  If I do again in the future, I'll have to re-visit this issue.  One thing they also said is that I *should* actively be sending out emails more often.  If you sign up for a website, then 6mon later they send you an email, by then you probably completely forgot about that site and just report it as spam.